# ZVS induction heater gets really hot diodes

Tags: diodes, overheat, zvs, induction-heater

I'm an embedded software developer and am trying to up my electronics and board design knowledge. As a good first exercise I made a ZVS induction heater. [project link](https://github.com/diondokter/induction-heater)

Once assembled I was happy to see that it worked! The oscillation is happening just fine and I can heat up metal.
But when I cranked up the voltage to 8 volts or so (my initial tests were at 4-5 volts), one of my diodes let out the magic smoke. Apparently they're getting really hot!

[image: Schematic]

It concerns the D1 and D2 diodes. They are the UF4005, but I've also tried the FR107 (of which I know it was used in another similar design) with the same results.

So now the question is why these diodes get so hot.

I could probably blindly copy one of the designs on the internet, but then I wouldn't understand what is going wrong.

I measured the voltage across one of the diodes (at a system lower voltage) and got the following result. (Green is voltage across diode, yellow is voltage across the big inductor and capacitors)

[image: Oscilloscope image]

This voltage looks really weird. Why does it stay high for so long when the voltage across the inductor switches? This is the only thing I could probe that looks really weird.

The only thing I could find that could be wrong is the component choice for L1 and L2. Instead of winding my own coils I bought them. It seems that these inductors can get saturated. I don't know how I could measure that in this circuit, so I'm not sure if that's happening. But say that it does happen, then I can't see why that would overheat the diodes. I would just waste more power than necessary, right?

Anyways, these are the components that I think are relevant:

- D1,D2: UF4005
- Q1,Q2: NTP067N65S3H
- C3,C4,C5,C6: MKS4O136806F00KYSD
- L1,L2: 2300HT-221-V-RC

The zener diodes don't do anything yet because the voltage is still too low.

The oscillation happens at ~40khz.

As a reference, here's a schematic of the same concept in a different form:
[image]

Comment: Any inductor with a magnetic core can saturate, whether you wind it yourself or buy it already wound. Are you able to measure any current waveforms? How high of a current is all this happening at--what current is going through the diodes that are getting hot? They're only rated for 1 A average, and only 2 W of power dissipation.

Comment: @Hearth I haven't measured that because I would have to add in some resistor somewhere to measure it. In my simulation of the circuit these diode only carry a maximum current of 22mA and an average of ~8mA at 8V VCC. The chosen components cannot dissipate a lot of power because they aren't supposed to

Comment: Why not simulate the circuit and see if it's doing what you intended it to do. You can also measure power dissipated in a sim. It would also help if you drew the circuit more like the one you copied. Using net names for connections on analogue circuits becomes so tiresome on a circuit so puny.

Comment: How are you probing across the diode? Most scope probes are grounded, this will likely disturb the circuit. A differential measurement technique is required.

Comment: *The chosen components cannot dissipate a lot of power because they aren't supposed to*  Then why did your hot diodes release the magic smoke.  Simulate it.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat if you look at the sentence above the one you quoted, you'd see that I did simulate it. 22mA is the max current . These diodes have also worked in other people's projects, so I'm quite sure that it's not the diodes that are wrong here

Comment: I have tried with values of components. Nothing "weird" even at 24 V. Ok, current through the "load" is 400 A -> 15 A through the power supply (360 W).